# @Html.ActionLink changes URLin address bar but doesn't redirect to destination In asp.net MVC-5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I have MVC view that displays diffrent angular views based on the condition. But once Angular views are loaded, none of the links on MVC page are working. When a link is clickedd on MVC view, address bar shows correct URL but doesn't load that URL. Found similar question was already asked but no answer was found. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enable `html5Mode` in your app. In such a case the location service will intercept any url change.

If you want some links to hit the server and load MVC pages, do one of the following

- Links that contain target element
  `Example: <a href="/ext/link?a=b" target="_self">link</a>`
- Absolute links that go to a different domain
  `Example: <a href="http://angularjs.org/">link</a>`
- Links starting with '/' that lead to a different base path
  `Example: <a href="/not-my-base/link">link</a>`

Comment: Tried all of them and didn't work. It works when I turnoff html5Mode. But that is not my intent.